# How to create a CheckBoxTile ListView?

Tags: class, flutter

So I'm making an app in and I need a listview of checkboxes. And afterwards it needs to display all the checked items on a new screen. So far what I tried gives me the listview but when I tap on one checkbox, all of them get checked. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
    bool yes = false
    Widget pro() =>
      Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          children: ListTile.divideTiles(
            context: context,
            tiles: [
              options("Apple"),
              options("Banana"),
            ],
          ).toList(),
        ),
      );

  Widget options(String head) =>
      CheckboxListTile(
        title: Text(head),
        value: yes,
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            yes = value;
          });
        },
      );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
 List<bool> isCheckedList = List.filled(2, false, growable: false);
 List<String> selectedItemsList = [];

    Widget pro() =>
      Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          children: ListTile.divideTiles(
            context: context,
            tiles: [
              options("Apple",0),
              options("Banana",1),
            ],
          ).toList(),
        ),
      );

  Widget options(String head,int index) =>
      CheckboxListTile(
        title: Text(head),
        value: isCheckedList[index],
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
             isCheckedList[index] = value;
             value ? selectedItemsList.add(head): selectedItemsList.removeWhere((item) => item == head);
          });
        },
      );
```

then pass the list while navigating to another page, in this way

```
Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => NewPage(selectedItemsList: selectedItemsList),
          );
```

then in the new page you can retrieve it this way

```
class NewPage extends StatelessWidget {
final List<String> selectedItemsList;
NewPage({this.selectedItemsList});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 

   
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to do the trick but I still need to print the checked ones...

Comment: where do you want to print ?

Comment: Anywhere. Preferably a new screen.

Comment: @ThatGuy let me know if this helps

Comment: Yup. Thanks a lot! I was wondering if I should create models and all

Comment: you can do it that way too.

Comment: Could you show me the model way as well? I'll post another question